# What datatype should I use for class properties when reading API data in XML from VBA

Tags: xml, vba, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to read a Web API call from a test program we have in Excel. Basically, I have VBA classes where all properties are currently of the Variant type. I'm trying to assign values to those properties from an API in XML format. I can get the XML data and pass it to my function that reads it. When the program hits the first line that assigns a value to a property, the code skips to the bottom of my function and exits without giving an error.

I had classes with actual data types, the code would read the XML data until it tried to assign a null value to a Double property type.

I'm assigning values like so:

```
with Object1
    .Property1 = XMLData.SelectSingleNode("//Parent/Child/Property1").text
End With
```

Comment: Text = String so use that

Comment: To add - you should probably make a few utility functions for reading values from your XML, so you can trap/report errors more reliably, without assuming every extraction will work without problems.  Your functions can also cast the data from the XML to the required type before assigning it to your class' properties.